why there is two pyspark.daemon process in spark worker node
when start a pyspark program, in the worker node, the process tree from ps -uxf is like below(I have simplified the java parameter etc.)
bob     241057  2.1  0.0 3380232 383300 ?      Sl   22:47   0:11 /third_party/java/jdk/1.8.0_72/bin/java org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 ubuntu_1:56014 -c 1 -m 11G
bob     241882 36.6  0.1 3264692 535552 ?      Sl   22:48   3:22  \_ /third_party/java/jdk/1.8.0_72/bin/java -Dspark.driver.port=42857--driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ubuntu_1:42857 --executor-id 0 --hostname 198.18.5.4 --cores 1 --app-id app-20241217224629-0000 --worker-url spark://Worker@198.18.5.4:39995 --resourceProfileId 0
bob     242279  0.3  0.0 179724 38512 ?        S    22:48   0:01      \_ /third_party/python3/bin/python3.8.bin -m pyspark.daemon
bob     242594 97.9  0.0 184844 33860 ?        S    22:48   8:54          \_ /third_party/python3/bin/python3.8.bin -m pyspark.daemon



process 241057 is worker process, which communicate to spark master and monitors and reports resource availability and, when directed by the master, spawns executors. The worker also monitors the liveness and resource consumption of the executors.
process 231882 is the executor process, performs the actual computation and data processing for the application
process 242279 is pyspark.daemon process which communicate to executor process
process 242594 is another pyspark.daemon process which runs real python related task like UDF function

Above is my understanding about the 4 processes, I am not very sure why there is two pyspark.daemon process, could someone share more light about this?

I think I found the answer from the comment of the source code here:

// Because forking processes from Java is expensive, we prefer to launch a single Python daemon,
// pyspark/daemon.py (by default) and tell it to fork new workers for our tasks. This daemon
// currently only works on UNIX-based systems now because it uses signals for child management,
// so we can also fall back to launching workers, pyspark/worker.py (by default) directly.


Nice old fashion obsevation:
First Daemon Process:

This acts as a Python worker manager that the Spark executor communicates with. Its primary responsibility is to set up and manage Python worker processes (the second daemon). It handles task allocation and data communication between the JVM (executor) and the Python environment.

Second Daemon Process:

This process runs the actual Python task, such as executing a UDF, performing transformations, or other Python logic defined in your application.
It processes the data sent by the JVM executor and returns the results back through the first daemon.

Hope I gave you that you were expecting to hear.
